# How to call OData functions with parameters from Olingo Java client?

Tags: java, olingo

I am using Olingo Java Client to fetch an odata service V4. I am not able to fetch the odata functions using Olingo. Olingo wiki was of no use. Can someone please help with this. If anyone can suggest another java based odata client that would be great too.

Comment: Please show us some code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
getFunctionInvokeRequest(URI uri, Class<T> resultRef, Map<String,ClientValue> parameters)
```

method at the InvokeRequestFactory. There you can specify the parameters which are used in the request.